# How to send data in AngularJs Sdk looppback factory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loopbackjs

I have this code in angular factory:

```
getPermissions: function(modelId){

var Pers = Permission.find({
    filter : {
        where : {
            and : [
            {
                user_id : $rootScope.userId
            },
            {
                permission_id : modelId
            }
            ]
        }
    }
}, function(data){
    var Pers = data;
});

console.log(Pers);
},
```

But in the console i get:

```
 [$promise: c, $resolved: false]
```

And in my app function:

```
$scope.optionsCrud = getFoo.getPermissions(2);

console.log($scope.optionsCrud);
```

I get in the console

```
undefined
```

And i can't succeed to run over the array.

What could I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return `Pers` like,

```
console.log(Pers);
return Pers;
```

Full Code,

```
getPermissions: function(modelId){
    var Pers = Permission.find({
        filter : {
            where : {
                and : [
                {
                    user_id : $rootScope.userId
                },
                {
                    permission_id : modelId
                }
                ]
            }
        }
    }, function(data){
        var Pers = data;
    });
    console.log(Pers);
    return Pers;
},
```

And then get your data like,

```
$scope.optionsCrud = getFoo.getPermissions(2);
$scope.optionsCrud.$promise.then(function(data){
// or just use, $scope.optionsCrud.then if not works
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: okay now it's not undefined but I still get  `[$promise: c, $resolved: false]` and I don't know how to run on the array